# Como impedir que um grid-item altere de tamanho quando adiciono texto?

Tags: css

Estou desenvolvendo um pequena ferramenta que pega um texto do usuário e gera uma versão criptografada  (cifra de César). Eu consegui construir o layout da GUI da forma que gostaria usando o modelo `grid-container`. Contudo, toda vez que o texto criptografado é gerado, o `grid-item` desse texto altera de tamanho.

Aqui está o código para replicar meu problema:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cifra de César</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1">   
            <textarea id="user-text" name="w3review" style="resize: none;">

        </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="item2"> 
            <div class="result">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">    
            <label class="label key" for="fname">Chave:</label>
            <input type="text" id="key" name="key"><br><br></div>
        <div class="item4"> 
            <button class="button button1" onclick="encrypt()">Criptografar</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```js
function caesar(message, key, mode){
    let SYMBOLS='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 !?.'
    let translated
    let translatedIndex

    for (symbol of message){
        if (SYMBOLS.includes(symbol)){
            let symbolIndex=SYMBOLS.indexOf(symbol)
            if (mode=="encrypt"){
                translatedIndex=symbolIndex+key
            }
            else if (mode=="decrypt"){
                translatedIndex=symbolIndex-key
            }
            if (translatedIndex>=SYMBOLS.length){
                translatedIndex = translatedIndex-SYMBOLS.length
            }
            else if (translatedIndex<0){
                translatedIndex = translatedIndex-SYMBOLS.length
            }
            translated=translated+ SYMBOLS[translatedIndex]}
        else {
            translated=translated+symbol
        }
    }

    return document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML =translated
}

function encrypt() {
    return caesar(message=document.getElementById("user-text").value,
    key=Number(document.getElementById("key").value), mode="encrypt")
}
```

style.css

```css
body {
    background: #070908;
    /* color: #E7F3FD; */
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text'
    'input-key enc-button enc-text enc-text';
    /* grid-template-columns: auto auto; */
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 50px 75px 75px 200px;

}

.item1 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    grid-area: input-text;
  }

.item2 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    grid-area: enc-text;
    text-align: justify;
}

.result {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 15px;
}

.item3 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    grid-area: input-key;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;

}

#key {
    width: 20px;
}

.item4 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    grid-area: enc-button;
    padding: 20px 0;

}

.button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.button1 {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
} /* Green */

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 15px;

  }
```

Como faço para o `grid-item` ficar com um tamanho fixo independente da quantidade de texto que ele recebe?

Comment: Na minha pesquisa anterior, achei essa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/431504/grid-variando-o-tamanho-conforme-o-texto . No entanto, o autor da resposta só postou o código, sem explicar. Então não entendi

Comment: Não precisa usar div necessariamente. Pode publicar a resposta, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade imediata é substituir o `<div class="result">` por um [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

```js
function caesar(message, key, mode) {
  let translated = "";
  for (s of message) {
    translated += mode == "encrypt" ? String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) + key) :
      mode == "decrypt" ? String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) - key) :
      s;
  }
  //Troquei o inner html por innerText para evitar injeção acidental de código.
  document.querySelector('.result').innerText = translated;
}

function encrypt() {
  return caesar(message = document.getElementById("user-text").value,
    key = Number(document.getElementById("key").value), mode = "encrypt")
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #070908;
  /* color: #E7F3FD; */
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-text input-text enc-text enc-text' 'input-key enc-button enc-text enc-text';
  /* grid-template-columns: auto auto; */
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 50px 75px 75px 200px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  grid-area: input-text;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  grid-area: enc-text;
  text-align: justify;
}

.result {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 15px;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  grid-area: input-key;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#key {
  width: 20px;
}

.item4 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  grid-area: enc-button;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


/* Green */

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cifra de César</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">
      <textarea id="user-text" name="w3review" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      <!-- Aqui substitui o div por um textarea-->
      <textarea class="result" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      <label class="label key" for="fname">Chave:</label>
      <input type="text" id="key" name="key"><br><br></div>
    <div class="item4">
      <button class="button button1" onclick="encrypt()">Criptografar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Também modifiquei a função `caesar()`, manipulando o código **UTF-16** de cada caractere em `menssage` somando ou diminuindo `key` de acordo com o `mode`.

Comment: Perfeito. E obrigado pela melhoria na função caesar tbm. A propósito vc sabe pq na miha versão da função o programa estava printando `undefined` junto com o output esperado?

Comment: @Lucas. Você inicia `translated` com `undefined` na linha `let translated`. Se trocar por `let translated = ""` o seu código não imprime mais o `undefined ` no inicio da saída.